# Copy file to iPhone app from Mac OS terminal

Tags: macos, iphone, terminal, data-transfer

Is there a way to copy a file from macOS into an iPhone app via Terminal? For example copy movie from Mac OS into the VLC Player App on iPhone.

Like iphone and mac os connected via cable, you run `copy /macos/file.mov /iphone/vlc` and it's all done.

Not share, copy, so it will be physically stored on iPhone and accessible anytime without internet.
I would prefer a solution through command line so as to be able to script it.

Comment: How important is the Terminal part of your question (does it need to be Terminal or would a UI based solution work as well)?

Comment: @nohillside I would like terminal, as I want to automate it and don't bother with that monkey work of copying files around.

Comment: You could look for a dnla server vl can download files from it and it can just run on your local wifi.

Comment: I am in search for this kind of function `scp` like, without the slow motion of Windows to open and fingers to click.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are looking for is called iOS File Sharing. You can copy files from macOS into an iOS app installed on iPhone/iPad if the iOS app supports File Sharing.

To copy files into an iOS app that supports File Sharing, you'd need to connect your iOS device to your Mac, and access the device via iTunes app (macOS Mojave and earlier) or Finder app (macOS Catalina and later)

Refer to the linked Apple Support document for detailed instructions:

1. macOS Mojave 10.14 and earlier:

   https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201301
2. macOS Catalina 10.15 and later:

   https://support.apple.com/kb/HT210598

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to do it manually, I just want to write script that would watch some folders and synchronise it with my iphone apps.